# @ShallowReference use case

Tags: java, javers

I try to understand the purpose of `@ShallowReference` by creating a test case but I don't see any differences in the Javers changes. My application is a Spring Boot application with repository annotation.

I have a one to many bidirectional relationship between `Customer` and `Project`. The test case creates a `Customer` and a `Project`, then the project is added to the customer. I tried to run the test case with and without the `@ShallowReference` on the `Set<Project>` field to see the `@ShallowReference` behaviour. Then I query the changes but they are the same in both cases. I am looking for a test case to understand the @ShallowReference.

Test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@Import({JaversSqlAutoConfiguration.class})
public class AuditTest {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    @Autowired
    private Javers javers;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Test
    public void testJavers() {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setName("Stackoverflow");
        customerRepository.save(customer);

        Project project = new Project();
        project.setName("Framework");
        customer.addProject(project);

        projectRepository.save(project);

        QueryBuilder jqlQuery = QueryBuilder.anyDomainObject().withNewObjectChanges();
        List<Change> changes = javers.findChanges(jqlQuery.build());
        assertEquals(9, changes.size());

        project.setName("Backend Framework");
        projectRepository.save(project);

        changes = javers.findChanges(jqlQuery.build());
        assertEquals(10, changes.size());

    }
}
```

Customer entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE customer SET deleted = true WHERE id = ?")
@Where(clause = "deleted = false")
public class Customer extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
//    @ShallowReference
    private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();

// Getter/Setter

    public void addProject(Project project) {
        projects.add(project);
        project.setCustomer(this);
    }

    public void removeProject(Project project) {
        projects.remove(project);
        project.setCustomer(null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Customer customer = (Customer) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, customer.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

Project entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECT")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE project SET deleted = true WHERE id = ?")
@Where(clause = "deleted = false")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Project extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Customer customer;

// Getter/Setter

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Project)) return false;
        Project project = (Project) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, project.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@ShallowReference` doesn't work for collections. We have an open issue for that https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/528
PR's are welcome.

Comment: Since Javers 5.3.0, @ShallowReference works for Collections and Maps.